# How to pass a Azure Blob Model to another class in .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net, azure, blob, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am experiencing with the `C#/.Net` world using `Azure Blobs`.

I made a Gallery that takes the images from an Azure Blob Storage, and displays it on the screen.

I want to create a `Partial View` from it, because of the `DRY` principle so I could reuse it in other files as well.

When I display the Partial View on the index it works well, but when I try to display it in the `Info.cshtml` file doesn't find the `Model` variable.

`Controller`

```
  public class ResourceController : Controller
        {
            const string blobContainerName = "blobContainer";
            static BlobContainerClient blobContainer;
    
            private IConfiguration _configuration;
    
            public ResourceController(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                _configuration = configuration;
            }
    
    
        // Create a List of images using Azure Blobs and Displays it on the Screen.
            { 
                try
                {
    
                    var s = _configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureConnectionString");
    
                    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(s);
    
                    blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName);
                    await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(PublicAccessType.Blob);
                    List<Uri> allBlobs = new List<Uri>();
    
                    foreach (BlobItem blob in blobContainer.GetBlobs())
                    {
                        if (blob.Properties.BlobType == BlobType.Block)
                            allBlobs.Add(blobContainer.GetBlobClient(blob.Name).Uri);
                    }
    
                    return View(allBlobs);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewData["message"] = ex.Message;
                    ViewData["trace"] = ex.StackTrace;
                    return View("Error");
                }
    
    
    
            }
          
    
            public ActionResult Info(){
    
        

 //This class doesn't see the Model variable
    
                return View();
            }
```

`Partial`

```
    //The Info class Doesn't see the Model variable

@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="imageBlock" value="GetGallery">
            <a href="@item" target="_blank"><img class="thumb" src="@item" alt="images"/></a><br />
            <div class="deleteDiv"><img class="deleteIcon" src="~/Images/deleteImage.png" title="Delete Image" onclick="deleteImage('@item');" /></div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

`ViewModel`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace AzureBlobLearning.Models
{
    public class ResourceViewModel
    {
        public string? RequestId { get; set; }

        public bool? ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);
    }

 

}
```

`Index.csthml`

```
//This displays the list of images
 <partial name="~/Views/Resource/_ResourcePartial.cshtml"  />
```

`Info.cshtml`

```
//This doesn't display
 <partial name="~/Views/Resource/_ResourcePartial.cshtml"  />
```

**My Question:**

- Why it doesn't see my Info view.
- How should I change my code so the Info sees the partialView?

*PS.: If you have any questions feel free to ask.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Why it doesn't see my Info view.

Because the action is just returning the View, with no Model inside.

Change from this:

```
public ActionResult Info(){
    //This class doesn't see the Model variable
    return View();
}
```

to this:

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    var model = LoadModelMethod();
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Info(){
    var model = LoadModelMethod();
    return View(model);
}


public List<Uri> LoadModelMethod()
{
    try
    {
    
        var s = _configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureConnectionString");
    
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(s);
    
        blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName);
        await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(PublicAccessType.Blob);
        List<Uri> allBlobs = new List<Uri>();
    
        foreach (BlobItem blob in blobContainer.GetBlobs())
        {
            if (blob.Properties.BlobType == BlobType.Block)
                allBlobs.Add(blobContainer.GetBlobClient(blob.Name).Uri);
        }
        return allBlobs;                    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewData["message"] = ex.Message;
        ViewData["trace"] = ex.StackTrace;
        throw;
    }
}
```

- How should I change my code so the Info sees the partialView?

you can do what I said above, extract the logic which loads the images to a method, and call it in both actions.

Comment: What is LoadModelMethod? Because it throws error, but I find anything on google?

Comment: I'll edit my answer, I thought it was clear

Comment: This code was almost prefect, I had to edit a bit but this is it.

Comment: vote up / mark as an answer if it was helpful